# Android Studio 4.1 y no muestra los errores subrayados

Tags: android-studio, ide

Recientemente he actualizado el Android Studio a la versión 4.1. Después de la actualización, el IDE no me muestra los errores subrayados en rojo o con la barra roja en el lado derecho. Tengo Windows 10.

He probado a

- eliminar la carpeta .graddle y .idea,
- invalidar cache y reiniciar,
- limpiar el proyecto y a volverlo a construir.

Tengo el Power Save Mode deshabilitado

Nada de esto me ha funcionado ¿Qué puedo hacer, para mí es fundamental a la hora de trabajar con el IDE?